# Buildfire - Can I send users paths to the app outside of the app itself?

Tags: buildfire

If I want a user fill out something within the app, can I give them a path that leads to the plugin within the app itself? For example when you try to open a google maps link on your phone and you have the google maps app it will just open the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to deep-link into the app from outside your app, this is achieved through custom schema and a deep-link. So each app is issued a unique schema on the OS. You're used to schemas like "http" or "ftp" and so on. Custom schemas are registered on the OS to let then operating system know if they see this schema/protocol that your app is responsible for consuming it. For example, facebook is "fb://". You can contact customer support to see if your app has been issued one and what is it.

The second part of this is to deep-link to a particular plugin you can find a quick shortcut to it on the control side of your plugin in the Control Panel
[image].

Once you've gotten the app to open, then made it navigate to the plugin you want. The last step is optional but good to know. YOu can pass query-string parameters to the plugin so it may take further action from within. For example, you can have it prefill information or navigate to a subsection of the plugin.

Here is an example:
`app683a5d://plugin/cb705192-fe4c-44e9-8032-34c9ee0a186a-1560793060569?firstName=Daniel&tel=555-555-5555`

- `app683a5d://` Tells the OS which app to open
- `plugin/cb705192-fe4c-44e9-8032-34c9ee0a186a-1560793060569` tells the app which plugin instance to open
- `?firstName=Daniel&tel=555-555-5555` passes along data to the plugin to consume

Here are some helpful references:

- Deep-Links https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Deep-Links
- Navigation from within the app https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Navigation

Comment: Thanks, how would this work with retrieving the data via the buildfire side. For example how would I be able to receive the firstName and tel attributes stated in the url?

Comment: you can call window.location.search just like you would on a website. Be careful there could be more parameters in there than just yours. On the other hand, if you use the standard deep-linking method you can just call `buildfire.deeplink.getData`